# How do I trigger an event in a database when a column has certain value?

Tags: mysql, cron

I am working on building a social network application similar to twitter where users have newsfeeds, followers, posts ect...
I am trying to implement a feature which would make posts (a post in my application is equivalent to a post on facebook) EXPIRE after a certain amount of time.
*What do I mean by expire?*

 1. Post disappears from news feed
 2. User whose post expires, relieves a notification alerting them that the post
has expired. On a programmatic level this is just a insert statement being executed when the post expires.

*What have I done so far?*

Making posts disappear from the newsfeed was simple, I just adjusted the query which return the newsfeed by checking the date_of_expiration column and compare it to NOW().

Creating notifications when the post expired was trickier.
My initial approach was to make a mysql CRON job which ran every 2 minutes, triggering an event which would select all posts where NOW() > date_of_expiration and use the selected data to insert a notification entry into my notification table.
This works, however, I do not want to use a CRON job. The 2 minute delay means a user might have to wait a full 2 minutes after the post actually expired before receiving the notification telling the user their post expired. I'm assuming if the table had many entries this wait time could be even greater depending on how long the it takes to run the select and insert statements.
*What am  I looking for?* 
Another solution to inserting a notification into the notification table when a users post expires.

I was thinking that if there was a way to create some kind of event that would trigger when the expiration date value for each row (in the posts table) is greater than NOW(), it would be a very good solution to my problem. Is something like this possible? What is commonly done in this scenario?

**FYI my stack is: MYSQL, JAVA with an Android+IOS front end, but I don't mind going out of my stack to accomplish this feature**

Comment: Just to clarify. With CRON you mean a real cron task (OS level) or do you mean a mysql EVENT?

Comment: Do you mark the expired posts in the posts table with a flag or something? Or how else do you know if a notification was already created? With a Join to the notification table?

Comment: Yes CRON job was not the correct term, I just used the term out of habit. The events are executed via the Mysql Event Scheduler.

Comment: Also, posts will get moved to a expired posts table to keep the posts table smaller thus quicker to query. However, that's only a future plan. Right now I use the join you mentioned

Comment: Can't you do a server-sent events where the application will check the database for new or expired event? you can read about it more here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how your application works. But here is a though, I have done in an application that interact with a telephone system where each second count.

I implemented a [server-sent event](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) where a script will keep checking for new updates every second. Then the script will update the client with any new/expired notifications.

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but it is worth sharing.

**EDITED**

Since you are leaning more toward having a table for the notification why now create the notification at run time with in a transaction?

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO posts(comment, createdBy....)Values('My new comment',123);

SELECT @lastID := LAST_INSERT_ID();

```
-- Create temporary table with all the friends to notify
-- "this will help you with performance" Hint then engine type
-- Make sure the final userId list is unique otherwise you will be
-- inserting duplicate notifications which I am sure you want to avoid
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myFriends (KEY(user_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY
SELECT 1 FROM users AS s
INNER JOIN friends AS f ON f.friedId = s.userId
WHERE s.userID = su.userID

-- insert the notifications all at once
-- This will also help you with the performance a little
INSERT INTO notifications(userID, postId, isRead)
SELECT userID, @lastID AS postId,'0' AS isRead
FROM users AS su
INNER JOIN myFriends AS f ON f.userId = su.userId;


-- commit the transaction if everything passed
commit; 
-- if something fails
rollback;
```

more thoughts, depending how busy you application will be things to consider

- Make sure your server is built with good hardware. lots of RAM 64GB+ and a good hard drives, SSD will be great if possible,
- Also, you may consider using GTID replication to have more sources for read.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the reply! I've never heard of server-sent events before but it sounds useful. However, I am looking for a way to generate the notifications programatically without needing to constantly query my tables (which is what I am doing right now.)

Comment: I am not sure that inserting/updating notifications is better for you than query the new data using server-sent events. Insert/update can be expensive. I updated my answer with another approach if you want to use a notification table

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer, since i don't understand well enough your database schema or the access pattern of the clients. However, I have some ideas that might help you:

What about marking the posts table as expired with a separate "expired" column? If you do that, you could select the posts that are to be sent to the client by getting all posts that are not marked as expired. This of course will include also the messages that are newly expired (NOW() > date_of_expiration) but are not marked yet. Let your java program sort the freshly expired posts out before sending the reply. At this point in your program you already have the posts that need to be marked and these are the exact same ones that need to be inserted into the notification table. You can just do that at this place in your Java program.

*Advantage*

No need for EVENTS or Cron jobs at all. This should be fairly efficient if you set indexes correctly in your tables. No need for a JOIN with the notification table.

*Disadvantage*

You need to store the expired info extra in a column, that may require a schema change.

Comment: I like that idea. Thanks!